# Why do people start going mad a week before Purim?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Last Thursday, a week before Purim, many of my Jewish friends and Jewish co-workers began [going mad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NCAA_March_Madness_(CBS/Turner)).

They were frantically writing names of colleges on a grid marked on paper. It looked like there were 64 college names in boxes, and they had to write 32 of these names into other boxes, then 16 more name, then 8, 4 2 and finally 1 name in a giant box in the middle of this grid.

I asked one guy what he was doing, and he was frantic and said that he had to "bracket" something or other. Another person I asked was also in a frenzy and said he was also "bracketing".

OK, so they fill these boxes exactly a week before Purim. They do this early in the morning. Then from late morning to late at night, they watch college basketball games on TV. For 3 weeks afterwards, they go mad while watching these games. Someone told me that this madness continues on Purim itself and Shushan Purim. (well, maybe getting drunk makes people mad.) The madness occurs on Shabbat and Sunday, as well. The madness lasts about 3 weeks, which means that it lasts from a week before Purim to a bit over a week after Purim.

Is there something about Purim or Adar Sheni that makes people mad to the point that they have to "bracket"?

Note - this madness seems to happen only in USA, for some reason.

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Writing on Shabbos?

Comment: @GershonGold I said that they go mad on Shabbat. The madness is not specifically related to their writing college names in a grid. I'll edit to explain the activity better.

Comment: Is this a US disease? Because it doesn't resonate at all with a European/Israeli?

Comment: Never heard of it in the USA. Must be very localized.

Comment: @GershonGold  It's definitely not just localized in the USA, it's widespread in the US. Around the same time people begin shouting at young people running around on televisions.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the 3 weeks of tisha bav? We limit happiness there, here we increase it.

Comment: @GershonGold See the link in the edited version.

Comment: Many nonJews go mad in the same way at the same time. I think that it must have to do with "Judaizers" trying to behave in the same way that Jews do.

Comment: @mbloch You may have a clever answer if you cite that source.

Comment: "Too localized"...Although I heard Kim Jong Un is meticulous about his bracket

Answer (score 2):

The time before Purim is very busy. We run in all directions to prepare the *mitzvot* of the day: we buy food for *mishloach manot*, buy for and prepare the festive Purim meal, culminating in a crazy Purim morning where we run across cities to listen to the megila reading, deliver *mishloach manot*, *matanot le'evyionim* and attend the festive meal with friends.

Our friendly gentile neighbors see us all excited, running all over the place and want to get in on the action, following the well-known *[hadran](http://www.sefaria.org/Hadran.4?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all)* said after learning *Masechet Megila*

> אָנוּ רָצִים וְהֵם רָצִים 
>  We run and they run

Our neighbors do not have the same mitzvot but observe this period according to their *minhag hamakom*. Your question describes a fairly specific North American minhag. In Europe I observed other practices which will culminate this year on the Sunday after Purim, e.g., running around gardens to hide [eggs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg) which [kids will then try to find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egg_hunt).

PS. Some say they copied the latter on the search for the Pessah's *afikoman* but I couldn't find an authoritative source for this in the Rishonim.

Comment: +1 for the clever citing. But, see if you can explain why this starts a week before Purim and ends before Pesach.

Comment: Come on Reb Dan, a week before Purim because that is when our wives start running to prepare the holiday. And it ends before Pesach because the omer period starts then and one curtails joy during the omer !

Comment: OK. Though, I know someone in my neighborhood that prepares for Pesach just after Chanukah. Now THAT sounds "mad".